# One of my partitions isn't shown anymore after I installed Ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

I bought my Asus in 2012. It came to me with FreeDOS. I installed Windows 7 and a few days ago I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.04.4 to my pc alongside Windows 7.

But I read about UEFI about problem which happens to new pcs. I have C, D, E partitions on my pc. Windows is in C. I wanted to install Ubuntu to E. The E partition has 58 GB. And 50 GB of it is empty.

And I parted that 50 GB to 30 GB. And in my boot menu there is something like that.

- boot option #1:UEFI: DVDRAM
- boot option #2:ht sata
- boot option #3:DVDRAM

I booted my pc using 3rd option thinking that my system is not in UEFI mode. There was  no any problem. I chose something else. And the disk partitions window has come. I knew my C, D. I did not touch them , But there also to partitons which are sda2 which is double clickable. The other one says that it can not be used and I chose the sda2 and formatted it in ext4 But swap area is not created. And I continued whithout formatting the swap area. But my Ubuntu and Windows works well. Only one problem my E partition has dissapeared. It is not important but I created different place for Ubuntu. Why is this happening?

Comment: It would be better if you upload gparted screenshot.

Comment: @user255742 Please, post your questions here, either as questions or in this comment section (if they relate to this current question). Also, that gparted screenshot would really help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your E partition disappeared because Windows doesn't recognize ext4 file system. Everything's normal. You have correctly installed Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

Linux recognizes window's NTFS file system but windows doesn't recognize the linux ext, ext4 disk format. So therefore your linux partition wont be shown in windows. But however you can still see the linux disk partition in the disk management which is shown normally. You don't have any problem in installation.